# How to upload json file on server?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I have a json file named "datetime.json" that returns that current date and time of the server, I have uploaded the file on my web host server.

When I call this on my website project via AJAX its not returning the current date and time of my webhost server. And also I'd like to format the time and date to something like this

```
Time: "hh:mm:ss AM/PM",
Date: "08/19/2016
```

Here is my JSON file:

```
[
  {
    date: '{{date(new Date("08/18/2016"))}}',
    time : '{{date(new Date("08:22:43 AM"))}}',
     timeZone: "Asia/Singapore"
    }
 ]
```

Update:
Okay I wrote the PHP file that returns my server's current time and date
http://cgbp.org/date.php

How do I extract the time and date contents via Ajax request in client side?
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://cgbp.org/date.php',
    success: function (result) {
      var InternetDate = new Date(result.date);
       var monthNames = [
                                                 "January", "February", "March",
                                                 "April", "May", "June", "July",
                                                 "August", "September", "October",
                                                 "November", "December"
                                               ];

```
                                           var weekday = new Array(7);
                                           weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
                                           weekday[1] = "Monday";
                                           weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
                                           weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
                                           weekday[4] = "Thursday";
                                           weekday[5] = "Friday";
                                           weekday[6] = "Saturday";

                                           var dayofweek = weekday[InternetDate.getDay()]; 
                                           var day = InternetDate.getDate();
                                           var monthIndex = monthNames[InternetDate.getMonth()];
                                           var year = InternetDate.getFullYear();


    //document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = dayofweek +', '+ monthIndex +' '+ day +', '+ year;
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = result.datecontents;
    document.getElementById('curdate').value = result.date;
}
```

});

Comment: Have you forgotten to add your code?

Comment: JSON is not a programming language. Uploading a JSON file to a server is not enough to cause parts of that file to change dynamically. You cannot "have a JSON file that returns" anything. JSON is just static text. You need to write a program that outputs JSON containing the values you expect.

Comment: I wanted to do something like this 

http://date.jsontest.com/

but uploaded on my web host server so it would return my timezone current date and time

Comment: @Eiz1993 Then you need to write software to do that, in something like PHP or Ruby on Rails or .Net or any other server-side programming language. You cannot write such a program in JSON, because JSON is not a programming language. JSON has no capacity to dynamically produce values like the current time.

Comment: Okay if I write it using PHP, will I be able to call its output to my website via AJAX? sorry for noob question.

Comment: @Eiz1993 Yes, that would work.

Comment: @meagar edited the question..